# VBA code to add a code before and after a certain value within the cell content

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a HTML style <> and </> before and after certain values within the contents of cells in Excel. For example, cell contains:

**Sales for January 2020**

If I wanted to add that before and after *January*. To look like: Sales of <>January</> 2020. Would that be feasible, please?

I am using `InStr(cell.Value, "A") > 0 Then` for finding the word in the sheet and `cell.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbLightGreen` to highlight them. But I cannot seem to be able to edit a certain part of the cell content? Has to be the whole cell. This is just a simplified example due to the nature of data used. But I require to add a

If so, any rough idea of what to use and how to go around that, also, please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Replace` Function: `Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, "January", "<>January</>")`.
[See here for details on the function.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function)